# How to connect AngularJS front-end and Python back-end using rest API?

Tags: python, angularjs, rest

I want to know about how to connect the two parts. If I am using Angular CLI as front-end and Python for my logic. So, I want to push text responses to my python back-end and then return a response for that. How do I do that?

Comment: You already answered your question: REST APIs are the communication method between backend and frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a webserver for your requests.
Flask, Django, ... are very popular, python based web servers.

There you define your routes (eg. /fetch-users) and it's logic.

In your frontend app, you can perform the requests via ajax.

Take care of "CORS" when your angular app is running on a different port than your backend!